# CoffeeScript generating dynamic variable names for objects (named classes)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm pretty new to the world of JavaScript and even newer to CoffeeScript. I have a problem and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Say I have a CoffeeScript class like this

```
class @Model
  constructor: (@name) ->
```

how could I pass the names of models to be created to a function to instantiate these objects whilst appending the name of the variable [in this case] with _model? Something like:

```
makeModel = (name) ->
  "#{name}_model" = new Model(name)
```

My rails app tells me that:

```
unexpected =
      "#{name}_model" = new Model(
                ^
```

I'm assuming that this is because of the string. Is there some sort of method to convert a string to a variable name? I took a quick look at the `.eval()` method but [the little book of CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html) warns against it's use.

Thanks

Comment: instead of a named variable, use an array or object to collect instances...

Comment: That did not occur to me. As a last resort this would be possible but as these elements are all stored in a database it would be far more convenient being able to interact with them by name than by maintaining an array

Comment: how is all.fred_model any eaiser to use than window.fred_model or even just fred_model? plus, if they are in an object, you8 can iterate all instances, which is messy with variables. i would also consider attaching them to the constructor itself as a static object property.

Comment: Again, new to JS and CS, would you mind expanding with some sort of code examples? the point is that I probably wouldn't need to iterate through all models but I would likely need to directly target say `current_model = fred_model` Sorry, complete noob here!

Comment: i don't know how it would look in CoffeeScript, but thanks to leaky assignments, you can just prepend an additional assignment after "var xxx=" in normal JS. something like "var xxx= self[name]= ... "

Comment: There is virtually no good reason to want to do this. You need to rethink how you're doing whatever you're doing, because this is a serious architectural problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ModelFactory = do -> 
  class @Model
    constructor: (@name) ->

  models = {}

  makeModel = (name) ->
    model = new Model(name)
    models["#{name}Model"] = model
    model

  getModel = (name) ->
    models["#{name}Model"] or makeModel(name)

  { getModel }
```

## Secret Magic:

**`do ->`** - The `do` keyword creates an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), a function that is called as soon as it is created. It can be used for creating modules like the following:

```
var myModule = (function () {
    var privateFunc = function () {};
    var publicFunc = function () { privateFunc(); };
    return {
        publicFunc: publicFunc
    }
})();
```

**accessing properties with strings** - In JavaScript, you can access a property of an object as a string, by using the [square-bracket (`[]`) notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), plus a string, or a variable containing a string. Here we are combining this with the CoffeeScript string interpolation sugar (`"#{}"`) to dynamically create property names and assign them.

```
var object = {
    prop: 'value',
    otherProp: 'otherValue'
};

var propertyName = 'prop';
var value = object[propertyName]; // 'value';

var something = 'Something'
object['my' + something] = 'a new property';
object.mySomething === 'a new property'; // true
```

Comment: This looks like a very good solution, thanks. two little things though , I really don't like using solutions without knowing what the code is doing. I don't suppose you know where I could read up on the `ModelFactory = do ->` business and this whole using strings as indices in arrays (`models["#{name}Model"]`)

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Nothing like being schooled before breakfast